# Passing data between UIs but before widget build

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter so bear with me. Currently I'm passing data from one ui to another. In the first UI I'm passing like this,

```
 await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return ItemCategory(itemDocId: returnDocID.toString());
        },
      ));
```

In the 2nd UI I'm trying to receive that data. Yes I know you can do it by 'widget.'. But I need to use it before the builder. So the 2nd UI code part is like this.

```
lass ItemCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  // Item Id
  final String itemDocId;

  const ItemCategory({super.key, required this.itemDocId});

  @override
  State<ItemCategory> createState() => _ItemCategoryState(itemDocId);
}

class _ItemCategoryState extends State<ItemCategory> {

static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    CatGrid1(itemDocId: widget.itemDocId),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
  ];

............


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

....................
```

as yiu can see on above coding I'm trying to send data to another ui called **CatGrid1** . But here comes the problem. I'm trying to send that string I passed from 1st ui to this 1. And a error comes and saying I can't use "widget.itemDocId". Which is the line "CatGrid1(itemDocId: widget.docId)"

And i fyou are wondering this list is for a drawer, but it's not something that closes. It's static. So when answering, I'm not expecting that.

Currently I tried passing with and without "widget." , But no luck getting what I want.

And as I'm new to flutter, I would really appreciate getting a custom code from someone rather than marking as a duplicate

As asked for CatGrid1,

```
class CatGrid1 extends StatefulWidget {
  // Item Id
  final String itemDocId;
  const CatGrid1({super.key, required this.itemDocId});

  @override
  State<CatGrid1> createState() => _CatGrid1State();
}

class _CatGrid1State extends State<CatGrid1> {
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(

..............
```

Error message,

> The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try
> replacing the reference to the instance member with a different
> expression dart (implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)

Comment: what do you mean by you cant use widget.itemDocId? can you show the exact error message? We also need to see your CatGrid1 code to understand what is going on

Comment: @Texv As i mentioned above in the question already, it's before "widget build". So it won't execute. I added changes as you asked

Comment: just replace 'static' with 'late'. So 'late final List<Widget> _widgetOptions'

Comment: @Texv I ended up using get package, which I also end up going for that method for my project.  Your answer actually works. If you can post that that as an answer I think that would be helpful as well. Anyways thanks for your answer, it works as well actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found an answer myself.But it is a flutter package. To parsing data, you can use a route manager called [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get). And if you use it to pass data, in the 2nd screen rather than initializing a separate variable, use 'get arguments'
So my list in the coding (which is where the error is), use that passed variable like this.

```
static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    CatGrid1(itemDocId: Get.arguments[0]),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
  ];
```

Pretty simple huh? Yes I'm gonna use this package for my future as well. I'm new to flutter, guess I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember you cannot directly assign class property to another variable, what you can do is you can store the **itemDocId** in a new variable like this:

```
late String newItemDocId;
@override
initState{
  super.initState();
  newItemDocId = widget.itemDocId;
}
```

then you can use the new variable as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `static` with `late`

```
late final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    CatGrid1(itemDocId: widget.itemDocId),
    const Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
    ),
    const Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
    const Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
  ];
```

you also don't need to pass it during createState as its useless and bad practice

```
State<ItemCategory> createState() => _ItemCategoryState(); //removed (itemDocId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement build function in ItemCategory, like this:

```
class ItemCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  // Item Id
  final String itemDocId;

  const ItemCategory({super.key, required this.itemDocId});

  @override
  State<ItemCategory> createState() => _ItemCategoryState(itemDocId);
}

class _ItemCategoryState extends State<ItemCategory> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
    children:[
    CatGrid1(itemDocId: widget.itemDocId),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    )]);
```

Comment: as shown above it's not under "@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) ". As I mentioned in the question "widget." doesn't work there